# Ninject GetBindings with Interface<T>

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to set up by Ninject kernel like so:

```
kernel.Bind<IPersist<SomeDataItem>>().To<SomeDataRepo>();
kernel.Bind<IPersist<AnotherItem>>().To<AnotherRepo>();
```

So that when my service recieves an instance of `SomeDataItem` - I find the appropriate repository / store to persist it:

```
kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IPersist<>))
      .Where(binding => binding.Service.GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(SomeDataItem))
```

However - I cannot get this to work. If I set up the container like as above, I get the `SomeDataRepo` as expected when I do:

```
kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IPersist<SomeDataItem>)) // SomeDataRepo
```

but this yields no results:

```
kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IPersist<>)) // Empty list
```

**Question**: How can query my container to get the instance of my interface that has generic argument T - where T is dynamic?

**EDIT**

Ok - using this I can at least get some results from `GetBindings()`:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IPersist<>)).To<SomeDataRepo>();
```

But I haven't gotten the right one out yet though using `.where()` on the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a very nice solution that is heavily inspired by this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21780153/896697.

Binding I do as follows, using [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.extensions.conventions/):

```
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind(
            x =>
            x.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
                .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom(typeof(IPersist<>))
                .BindSingleInterface());
```

And for resulution I use:

```
public class ResultsAgent : IResultsAgent
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo GenericProcessMethod = typeof(ResultsAgent).GetMethod("ProcessGeneric");

    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public ResultsAgent(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public void Store(SearchResult message)
    {
        GenericProcessMethod.MakeGenericMethod(message.GetType())
            .Invoke(this, new object[] { message });
    }

    public void ProcessGeneric<TMessage>(TMessage message)
        where TMessage : SearchResult
    {
        var handler = this.resolutionRoot.Get<IPersist<TMessage>>();
        Console.WriteLine("ResultsAgent will use: " + handler.GetType().FullName + " to persist");
        handler.Persist(message);
    }
}
```

The smartness in the `ResultAgent` comes from the mentioned stackoverflow - which uses reflection to create a call to the generic method ( `ProcessGeneric` ) which then calls into the kernel with `Kernel.Get<>` to get the appropriate handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bind(typeof(IPersist<>)).To(typeof(GenericDataRepo<>));
```

then when you do:

```
kernel.Get<IPersist<SomeDataItem>>();
```

you will get `GenericDataRepo<SomeDataItem>`

Comment: Thanks - but the problem wasn't as much binding the instance - but more finding a dynamic way to resolve the service from the compositionroot.